# Swift Custom UITableViewCell not displaying data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am new to Swift, and iOS development in general.  I am attempting to create a custom UITableViewCell.  I have created the cell in my main storyboard on top of a UITableView that is inside a UIViewController. When I loaded one of the default cells, I was able to populate it with data.  However, now that I am using a custom cell, I cannot get any data to appear in the table.  I have gone through all kinds of tutorials and questions posted on the internet, but I can't figure out why it is not working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for the UIViewController that the tableview resides in.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //self.tblView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier : "Cell")
        self.tblView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier : "Cell")
        tblView!.delegate = self
        tblView!.dataSource = self

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataMgr.data.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : CustomTableViewCell = self.tblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath : indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        var values = dataMgr.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.newTotalLabel?.text = "\(values.newTotal)"
        cell.winLoseValueLabel?.text = "\(values.newTotal - values.currentTotal)"
        cell.dateLabel?.text = "5/17/2015"


        return cell
    }
}
```

I have stepped through the program where it is assigning values to the cell variables.  The variable 'values' is being populated with data, but when stepping over the assignment lines to the cell variables, I found that they are never assigned.  They all remain nil.

Comment: Have you connected the cell's properties (IBOutlets) to the storyboard's labels?

Comment: Yes, I created the outlets by control dragging from the labels directly into my custom table cell controller code.

Comment: If cell.newTotalLabel, etc., is nil, it doesn't sound like it's hooked up to the storyboard cell.  Also check to see that your storyboard cell is set to its custom class.  Otherwise, those properties would be nil since they don't exist on a UITableViewCell.

Comment: I just reattached the winLoseValueLabel again by control dragging into my custom class.  In my storyboard, the cell class in the identity inspector is set to my custom class, the style is set to Custom in the attributes inspector, and the identifier is labeled Cell.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you make a custom cell in the storyboard, don't register the class (or anything else). Just be sure to give the cell the same identifier in the storyboard that you pass to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: That did it.  I commented out all the code in the viewDidLoad function besides the call to the super class, and the data populated. Thanks!

Comment: This was simply amazing as I got to learn when not to use register class