# TableViewCell does not get data in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using a Custom TableViewCell in TableViewController.
Even the data is getting populated but my TableViewCell does not display it.

Here is my Custom TableViewCell Code

```
class PlaceItemCellCustom: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var placeFace: UILabel?
   @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel?

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
   } 

}
```

Here is my TableViewContoller

```
class PlaceListViewController: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      loadListFromSource()
   }
  
   // Other code

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return places.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 100
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let place = places[indexPath.row]
       // I am getting the data 
       print(place.placeName?.description ?? " " )
    
       let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceListIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! PlaceItemCellCustom
    
       customCell.placeName?.text = place.placeName
   
       return customCell
   }

}
```

What am I missing here? I am new to IOS app development.
Found similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338566/swift-custom-uitableviewcell-not-displaying-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) but did not help

## Edit: It was working fine for the default TableViewCell.

But when I changed it to custom TableViewCell it does not work. I have set the class name in the storyboard as well.

> Here is my Storyboard

[image]

> Here is the output

[image]

Comment: You have to call `reloadData` after populating `places`.

Comment: It was working fine with the Default TableViewCell. But when I changed to custom TableViewCell it does not work. I was calling self.tableView.reload() function in the code @vadian

Comment: Did you already connect the `@IBOutlet`? Because I'm sure this is not xcode `@IBOutlet`, but you create your own `@IBOutlet` right?

Comment: Yes I did connect the IBOutlet in Storyboard by ctlr+drag @AchmadJP

Comment: On the cell, after `super.awakeFromNib()`, call `placeName?.text = "test"`. Did it show up?

Comment: yes it does show up @AchmadJP

Comment: Did you set cell identifier to PlaceListIdentifier? and you can assure that        print(place.placeName?.description ?? " " ) gives you data?

Comment: Yes, I have set the identifier. and it does give the data@JVprint(place.placeName?.description ?? " " )  @JVS

Comment: can you try in your cellForRow to exchange your last line with "customCell.placeName!.text = place.placeName" - note the exclamation mark @ placeName. And see if it ends in an exception

Comment: I changed it and got this error message. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value @JVS

Comment: Create a function in UITableViewCell class where you can setData and then call that function from cellforrowAt and pass whatever data you want to pass. And set placeName.text = data in TableViewCell class. @RohitSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I can understand you must have forgotten to connect the `IBOutlet` of placeName in PlaceItemCellCustom:

[image]

In your PlaceItemCellCustom keep placeName as :

```
@IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!
```

and in `cellForRowAt`:

```
customCell.placeName.text = place.placeName
```

in this way if you forgot to connect segue Xcode will throw error as :

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

You can read more about it here :

- https://cocoacasts.com/should-outlets-be-optionals-or-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Comment: I did connect both the outlets. And it was there. But when you suggested it. I rechecked it and found that they were not there. Strange. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You need using this method for get data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return places.count
}
```

Comment: I do have that in my code. That's why the list getting populated. It's just that it does not get data on the view